# Want to create array with sub arrays so I can loop through JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to create subarrays and am very new to this. My terminology isn't great so bare with me. I am using the current PHP code to generate a JSON array. The JSON output is below.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $points = $row['points'];
    $price = $points*20;
    $pricefrmt = "$".number_format ($price, 2);

    $return['resort'][$row['resortcode']][] = [
        'resort' => $row['resortname'],
        'roomcode' => $row['roomcode'],
        'room' => $row['roomname'],
        'view' => $row['viewname'],
        'checkin' => $checkin,
        'checkout' => $checkout,
        'available' => $row['available'],
        'price' => $pricefrmt,
        'points' => $row['points'],
        'sleeps' => $row['sleeps'],
        'sleepdetails' => $row['sleepdetails'],
        'bedding' => $row['bedding'],
        'sqfoot' => $row['sqfoot'],
        'roomdescription' => $row['roomdescription'],
        'amenities' => $row['amenities'],
        'layoutimg' => $row['layoutimg'],
        'roomimg' => $row['roomimg'],
        'roomimgthumb' => $row['roomimgthumb'],
    ];
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

The code below seems to create an array? with subarrays? But, resort: doesn't give me an array number? I assume this doesn't allow me to look through resort?

Everything under SSR has [0],[1],[2] etc beneath it. However, everything under resort: SSR, VGF, etc does not. I will be using a loop to generate HTML and I can't seem to loop the resort portion.

```
{resort: {…}}
resort:
SSR: Array(7)
0: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "TA", room: "Deluxe Studio", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
1: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "S9", room: "Deluxe Studio", view: "Preferred View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
2: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "TB", room: "1-Bedroom Villa", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
3: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "SB", room: "1-Bedroom Villa", view: "Preferred View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
4: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "TL", room: "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
5: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "TC", room: "2-Bedroom Villa", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
6: {resort: "Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa", roomcode: "TP", room: "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa", view: "Preferred View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
VGF: Array(9)
0: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "86", room: "Deluxe Studio", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
1: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "81", room: "Deluxe Studio", view: "Lake View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
2: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "87", room: "1-Bedroom Villa", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
3: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "82", room: "1-Bedroom Villa", view: "Lake View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
4: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "89", room: "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
5: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "88", room: "2-Bedroom Villa", view: "Standard View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
6: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "84", room: "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa", view: "Lake View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
7: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "83", room: "2-Bedroom Villa", view: "Lake View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
8: {resort: "Disney's Grand Floridian Resort & Spa", roomcode: "85", room: "3-Bedroom Grand Villa", view: "Lake View", checkin: "2021-06-14", …}
```

I don't feel like it is needed, and I know this javascript isn't correct, but it gives an idea of what I am looking at. I don't currently have the initial "resort" loop in here.

```
$(function getData() {
  $("#searchbtn").click(function () {
    var checkin = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var checkout = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var occupants = document.getElementById("party").value;
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { checkin: checkin, checkout: checkout, occupants: occupants },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.resort.SSR[4].roomcode);
        searchresult(response);
      }
      });
      let searchresult = function(response) {
      let container = document.getElementById('resultsbox');
      let output = "";
      
        for (let j = 0; j < response.resort.SSR.length; j++) {
          output +=
            "<div class='roomresults'>"+
            "<div>" + response.resort.SSR[j].room + " - " + response.resort.SSR[j].view + "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        }
      
        $(container).html(output);
      }
});
});
```

Any help is appreciated and I am just trying to learn and understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> array with sub array

```
<?php $data = array(
              'name'=>'ali',
              'lastname'=>'ahmadi',
              'emails'=> array(
                            'email1'=>'ali1@gmail.com',
                            'email2'=>'ali2@gmail.com',
                            'email3'=>'ali3@gmail.com',
                            )
              )?>
```

> to JSON

```
$toJSON = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: $data = array(
    'resort' => $row['resortname'],
    'resortcode' => $row['resortcode'] => array(
            'room' => $row['roomname'],
            'view' => $row['viewname'],
            'checkin' => $checkin,
            'checkout' => $checkout
    )
) 

Returns: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "=>", expecting ")"